# can't access specific files in bindfs mount

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, hfs+

I'm using Arch Linux on a Mac and therefore use `hfsprogs` to access my `hfs+`-partitions. Since the permissions on the files on my Mac partitions are set to my Mac user, I can't read or write those partitions with my Arch Linux user. To address this problem, I use a `bindfs` mount like this:

```
bindfs -u $(id -u) -g $(id -g) /mnt/mac-hdd-orig /mnt/mac-hdd
```

Run as my normal user, `/mnt/mac-hdd-orig` is the mountpoint of my Mac hdd:

```
/dev/sda2 on /mnt/mac-hdd-orig type hfsplus (rw,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8)
```

This results in the following mount point:

```
/mnt/mac-hdd-orig on /mnt/mac-hdd type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000,default_permissions,allow_other)
```

This works fine for most files, but however, there are certain directories I can't access in the bind mount, although their permissions don't differ from other files / directories:

Accessing `/mnt/mac-hdd/Users/username/Bitcoin/` works fine in the `bind`-mount:

```
ls -ahl /mnt/mac-hdd/Users/username/Bitcoin/|head -n 7
total 3,8M
drwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1000   12  6. Jan 02:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1000   10 11. Jan 02:13 ..
-rw------- 1 1000 1000   37  8. Sep 00:39 banlist.dat
drwx------ 1 1000 1000 1,3K 25. Sep 21:21 blocks
drwx------ 1 1000 1000  857 26. Sep 09:51 chainstate
-rw------- 1 1000 1000    0  8. Sep 00:37 db.log
[...]
```

But however, I can't access any files or directories in that directory, even as root:

```
sudo cat /mnt/mac-hdd/Users/username/Bitcoin/db.log
     cat: /mnt/mac-hdd/Users/username/Bitcoin/db.log: Permission denied

sudo ls -ahl /mnt/mac-hdd/Users/username/Bitcoin/blocks/
     ls: reading directory '/mnt/mac-hdd/Users/username/Bitcoin/blocks/': Permission denied
     total 0
```

What's wrong with my `bindfs`-mount? Other directories work fine. The original mount lists that directory as follows:

```
sudo ls -ahl /mnt/mac-hdd-orig/Users/username/Bitcoin/|head -n 7
total 3.8M
drwxr-xr-x 1 501 utmp   12 Jan  6 02:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 501   80   10 Jan 11 02:13 ..
-rw------- 1 501 utmp   37 Sep  8 00:39 banlist.dat
drwx------ 1 501 utmp 1.3K Sep 25 21:21 blocks
drwx------ 1 501 utmp  857 Sep 26 09:51 chainstate
-rw------- 1 501 utmp    0 Sep  8 00:37 db.log
[...]
```

and:

```
sudo ls -ahl /mnt/mac-hdd-orig/Users/username/Bitcoin/blocks|head -n 5
total 90G
drwx------ 1 501 utmp 1.3K Sep 25 21:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 501 utmp   12 Jan  6 02:26 ..
-rw------- 1 501 utmp 128M Sep  8 00:47 blk00000.dat
-rw------- 1 501 utmp 128M Sep  8 00:48 blk00001.dat
[...]
```

`chmod -R g+r /mnt/mac-hdd-orig/Users/username/Bitcoin/` didn't help. `chmod -R o+r /mnt/mac-hdd-orig/Users/username/Bitcoin/` did result in the following strange result:

```
sudo ls -ahl /mnt/mac-hdd/Users/username/Bitcoin/blocks|head -n 5
total 0
drwxr--r-- 1 1000 1000 1.3K Sep 25 21:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1000   12 Jan  6 02:26 ..
-????????? ? ?     ?        ?            ? blk00000.dat
-????????? ? ?     ?        ?            ? blk00001.dat
```

Any ideas what could fix that problem? I appreciate any help a lot!